# J2Objc Eclipse Plugin "error: --ignore-missing-imports is no longer supported"

Tags: java, objective-c, eclipse, j2objc

When I use the [J2Objc Eclipse Plugin](https://github.com/hemantasapkota/j2objc-eclipse-plugin) I get the following error while translating my code:

```
Executing with switches: [ -g --no-package-directories -x objective-c -use-arc --verbose --ignore-missing-imports --prefixes /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TEST2Objectc/.TEST2Objectc-prefixes  ]
/Applications/J2Objc/j2objc-0.9.6/j2objc -g --no-package-directories -x objective-c -use-arc --verbose --ignore-missing-imports --prefixes /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TEST2Objectc/.TEST2Objectc-prefixes -encoding UTF-8 -d /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TEST2Objectc/src /Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TEST2Objectc/src/java/ios/Test.java
error: --ignore-missing-imports is no longer supported
```

I do not see any option to change the `--ignore-missing-imports` flag.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--ignore-missing-imports` flag [has been removed by J2Objc developer](https://github.com/google/j2objc/commit/88c907971f7af1915d5b462a90463dfdaeee0670)

[Because](https://github.com/google/j2objc/issues/432)

> That flag is only useful when doing a first
>   pass over a large project, and shouldn't be used normally since all that
>   does is ignore an error that will show up when compiling the generated
>   files.

You should uncheck "Continue translation if an imported class is not found on the class or source paths" for now

Anyway, j2objc-eclipse-plugin developers should remove it.

Comment: Plugin developer here. The plugin has been updated with changes for J2OBJC 0.9.6. See https://github.com/hemantasapkota/j2objc-eclipse-plugin